# Can we run sqlcmd from RDS instance?

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have an EC2 instance for a .NET application and a RDS instance for SQL Server Express. Since Express doesn't support Sql Agent Jobs we need to use sqlcmd and schedule it as a batch. Can the batch file be setup in the RDS instance and if so how? If not, are there other free alternatives without setting up the SQL server in EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have to use some `PowerShell` commands from your EC2 instance for .Net app against the RDS instance..

A sample command would like below

```
C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance -Database EduData –Query “SELECT id, name, value, testscore FROM TestScores” –Username -Password
```

NOTE: I think you would need the SQL Client software installed on your .Net app EC2 instance to be able to do this.

Now you can create your batch jobs on your EC2 instance.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You actually cannot RDP into an RDS instance:

From [Microsoft SQL Server on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html)

> In order to deliver a managed service experience, Amazon RDS does not
>   provide shell access to DB instances

So you cannot run `sqlcmd` directly on the instance. Likewise for batch files, they cannot be installed on the RDS instance.

As @vmachan suggested, you will need to install the client tools on a separate instance in order to access command line functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command below. It works for me.

> "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S
>   "xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -d database -U user_id -P
>   password -i "path\SqlQueryName.sql"

or without database name

> "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S
>   "xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -U user_id -P password -i
>   "path\SqlQueryName.sql"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call CMD file from RDS instance. Unlike with on Prem sql servers where cmd can be called from a sql server agent job, in RDS it’s not possible. I had a task of stopping DMS task in sql server agent job and then do a fresh restore of the database using backup. This task of stopping DMS wanted to have it in sql agent job, tried a lot & the only solution I see was having this DMS task in a batch file outside the sql agent job and then running it first and then sql agent job to do the restore. Any other useful tips or solutions will be appreciated! Thanks! Note : it’s RDS and not sql on EC2.